# Saving shell-mode state using elscreen between sessions in Emacs

Tags: shell, emacs, workspace

I like `elscreen` for the idea of screens / workspaces (pretty much reminds me of 
i3).

I'm also using `elscreen-persist` to save configs between sessions.

However, I'd like to define some default shells, but this information is not being saved.

Does anyone have an idea how it would be possible to save `shell-mode` state?

Actually, most importantly is of course the fact that now it starts in *scratch* after loading (rather than in its old shell), while I'd like it to start a shell with the prompt at the part where it ended.